# Environment Variables not in Python interpreter

Tags: python, environment-variables

HI i just run over a curious thing.

In my .bashrc looks like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Build/Utilities/VTKPythonWrapping/site-packages:home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Build/bin

ParaView_DIR=/home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Build

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Builds/bin
```

So now when i start the python interpreter and type following:

```
>>>os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
 raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

same error with `ParaView_DIR`, but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has the additional Path.

in the shell they exist.

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Build/Utilities/VTKPythonWrapping/site-packages:home/pschu/ParaView-3.14.1-Build/bin
```

now when i do

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH
```

before I run the python interpreter it works.

What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
% PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/tmp python
```

In Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
':/tmp'
```

Comment: What, without an `export` or `setenv`?

Comment: Yes, since the environment variable and the started `python` programm are on the same line. In this case no export is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you `export` the variables?

```
export PYTHONPATH ParaView_DIR
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH was probably already exported in one of your other startup files.  Once a variable is exported it stays that way.

Exporting a variable makes it an *environment variable*, if you don't `export` then it is just local to the shell and a child process does not get a copy.

If you are using the C-shell (often indicated by the % prompt) then the syntax is different:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH
```